# How to convert html (including css) file to pdf in java

Tags: java, file, wkhtmltopdf, file-conversion, openhtmltopdf

I am writing java program that takes html (including css) file and converts it to pdf file. The problem is that my html file is not validated means, there is some tags which are not closed, and other small errors. I tried almost all java libraries, but the problem is still not solved. If html file is validated then there is not any problem with converting. But if file is not validated then remaining part is quite challenging for me. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: try to check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71111688/how-to-convert-html-css-to-pdf-using-java

Comment: No actually, none above of them didn't solved my question, the results are quite different. Why chrome print works okay but any Java library fails